# Execute Javascript code(in a seperate file), within an AJAX success response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to execute a Javascript file *(which puts the Google Maps API on a div)* **when the AJAX success response occurs.

I have the AJAX success displaying some JSON values, but I would like to execute the Javascript file within the same success response.

I have the following code so far in my *"main.html"* file:

```
        <form id="display" method="post" action="PHP_Function_2.php">

        <input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Display Location Evidence On Map" />

    </form>

        <script>
        $(function(){
          $("#display").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: $(this).attr('action'),
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function(data)
                     {                 
                        //display data...
                        //("#results").html(data.name).show; 
                        $("#results").empty();

                        console.log(data);

                        $("#map-canvas").empty();

                        $("#results").append(data); 

                        $(document).on("ready",function()
                        {
                                $.getScript( "Map_2.js" );              
                        }

                   });                
          });
        });

        </script>
```

And the following Javascript code in: *"Map_2.js"* **that I would like to execute on ajax success.** Which initializes the map on *"the map-canvas"* div:

```
function initialize() {



var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have been trying to use the getScript() function, but I am having trouble with it. Bit of a beginner with HTML and Jquery.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to execute the Javascript file"? Which file?

Comment: Please elaborate on the trouble you have. The better you describe your issue, the easier it is for us to help you, and almost more importantly, the easier it is for other readers to identify their problem as yours. Also, the text formatting options bold and italic are for emphasizing part of the text. It kind to defeats its purpose if everything is bold.

Comment: Apologies.

When the AJAX success response comes back, I would like execute all of the code within the external Javascript file (to put the map on the "main.html" page)

I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

1. Include the map2.js file in your main.html file.
2. Call the initialize function in the success of the ajax call.